# Bug Chrome lineas horizontales blancas

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome

Hola resulta que tengo un boton que despliega una serie de opciones con una animacion de css.

Pero al momento de desplegarse deja unas extrañas lineas blancas que dañan el estilo.

Alguna ves tuvieron un problema similar que me recomienda hacer aqui.

les dejo el gif
https://gfycat.com/vigilantkeyhammerkop

Al parecer solo pasa en Chrome

la clase css que hace la animacion es esta

```
float: right;
width: 140px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
top: -3px;
padding-top: 3px;
-webkit-animation-name: showMenu;
animation-name: showMenu;
transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
animation-duration: 2s;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solucion es simple, tienes que ponerle el atributo `box-shadow: none;` al boton

Comment: Hola Brian Martinez, Efectivamente quite el box shadow funciono perfectamente muchas gracias, podrías explicarnos porque pasa?

Comment: @alejandro esto pasa porque el navegador por predeterminado coloca un box-shadow automaticamente para ahorrarte el trabajo